# spark dataframe in worker process

Tags: apache-spark

I need to broadcast a dataframe to the worker process to be used in it. This is what I am trying

```
val currencydf = sqlContext.read.format(constants.CASSNADRA_CLASS).options(Map( "table" -> constants.CASSANDRA_TABLE_EXCHANGE, "keyspace" -> constants.CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE)).load
currencydf.cache
val bdCurrencyDF = sparkContext.broadcast(currencydf)
```

When I pass it to

```
foreachPartition{

val currencyDataFrame = bdCurrencyDF.value
```

I get a null pointer exception in java for the dataframe.

If this is not possible can someone please answer this
1) how to create a dataframe from a table in executor process? Do we have access to sparkcontext or sqlcontext ?
2) If not, how can I pass a dataframe from driver to executor

Comment: 1) It is not possible 2) It is possible but you useless since you  won't be a able to use any of its methods.

Comment: oh then in that case. I will need to use the direct cassandra queries inside it by creating session. Thanks for this info

Answer (score 0):

1. As indicated in the doc, dataframes are not boradcast by a call to `cache`, but by a call to `Broadcast`, which is absent in your example.
   https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables
2. Have you considered doing a simple broadcast join ? As of SPARK-8300, users can now do
   `left.join(broadcast(right), "joinKey")`
   to give the query planner a hint that "right" DataFrame is small and should be broadcasted.

Comment: Sorry I just forgot to add the broadcast line. Edited the code.